# The nodejs console application fails to obtain an AD token while a similar .NET app does not

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-angular

I have the following configuration in place (the actual values are masked) in a .NET 6.0 console application that obtains AD tokens successfully:

```json
{
"Tenant": "MASKED", //this is the same as tenantId
"ClientSecret": "MASKED",
"Scope": "api://MASKED/.default",
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}",
"ClientId": "MASKED"
}
```

The C# code (a console/daemon app) that acquires the token successfully as per the following code snippet:

```cs
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri(GetAuthority()))
                .Build();
            var scopes = new string[] { Scope };
            try
            {
                var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
                response.Result = result.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (MsalServiceException mex) when (mex.Message.Contains("AADSTS70011"))
            {
                _logger.LogError(mex, $"The scope provided is not supported. {mex.Message}");
            }

GetAuthority() => string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Instance!, Tenant);
```

I am using the same parameters in the provided nodejs console application, but I get the following error message. Not sure whether or not it's related to using a scope as api://MASKED/.default.

If I use the scope as the graph's URL, the token will be acquired successfully, but the validation code in the backed won't recognize the token as a valid one due to the scope inconsistency.

> AADSTS900023: Specified tenant identifier 'MASKED' is neither a valid DNS name, nor a valid external domain.

The nodejs app should acquire a token successfully, or if a point regarding the scopes like api://MASKED/.default

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

In my appsettings  below is my configuration.

***appsettings.json***

```
{
    "AzureAd": {
      "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "Domain": "testthetenant365.onmicrosoft.com",
      "ClientId": "xxx",
      "TenantId": "wrong tenantId or spaaces",
      "ClientSecret": "xxxxxx",
      //"Scope": "api://xxxe/.default",
      "ClientCertificates": [
      ],
      "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    },
    "DownstreamApi": {
      "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
      "Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    },
```

when I gave wrong tenant id or domain and run in Visual studio, I got below error:

[image]

When I checked the same in postman ,got similar error that you got :

```
 "error_description": "AADSTS900023: Specified tenant identifier 'xxx' is neither a valid DNS name, nor a valid external domain.\r\nTrace ID: xxx\r\nCorrelation ID: 06c6fb9d-2bd6-4b86-b6db-1f5a180eeaae\r\nTimestamp: 2023-01-18 10:32:23Z",
```

[image]

It was due to wrong tenant Id, please check if you have given tenant Id other then your tenant or has some digit missing in it.

It must be even due to spaces at start or end of tenant Id .
When I corrected it , I could get the token successfully:

[image]

Also make sure to **expose the API** , if you are calling api other than Microsoft graph.

[image]